# centos install] how to install program in the user account using yum

Tags: centos, yum

I'm now using centos5.8 .

And I'm not administrator, I mean I'm just have user account, not root.

Currently I'm installing program in this way.
Download source and move to the my account and install using make.

But current way is too difficult to me.

So I really want to use more easy way.
Like sudo apt-get install.

Yum looks like that.
But when I tried to use yum, he required root account.

I know root password but..

Can I use yum?
I'm afraid about it can destroy the whole system.
I just want to change my account not shared directory and file.
I want to install program in /home/ME/
not ../../etc ../../bin

How can I do this?
And is it safe to use yum?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Yum, you need to have root access.

You can compile and run application in your home directory without root access, but systemwide installing using yum is not possible without root access.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm confusing about your answer. what I want to do is install program in my home directory using yum. I can get root password. But I don't want any change in root program, I mean I don't want to affect other people. Is it possible?

Comment: There is basically no easy way to install applications using yum without root access. You should ask if your sysadmin could install the applications you need.